# Select/edit all children elements inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I use jquery or css to assign a .class to all  elements inside a div?

i.e this is what I have

```
<div class="nav">
   <a href="">one</a>
   <a href="">two</a>
</div>
```

But this is what I want

```
<div class="nav">
   <a href="" class="test">one</a>
   <a href="" class="test">two</a>
</div>
```

Using as little code as possible, so that when the page loads, the  elements in .nav have the class "test" assigned to them and I don't have to assign it in every single

Comment: have you considered just using CSS selector to solve your problem, like so: `.nav > a { background: red; }`?

Comment: Well, I'm using a different jquery script to edit other aspects of the page based on the class assigned to the <a> elements. i.e if the user clicks a link in that div, based on the class, the text color of the link changes

Comment: You might want to also include the before and after or current and expected result to add more information.

Comment: `$('.nav a').addClass('test');`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I did include the before and after. Before, without the script, the <a> elements don't have a class assigned to them. With the script, the <a> elements then have class="test" assigned to them

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="">one</a>
            <a href="">two</a>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('div > a').addClass('test')
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple in jQuery: `$('div a').addClass('class');`

Or in JavaScript something like this:

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll("div a");

for(let link of links) {
  link.classList.add("class");
}
```

```css
.class {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
   <a href="">one</a>
   <a href="">two</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { $('.nav a').each(function(){ $(this).addClass("Test"); }) });
```

```css
.Test{
color:red
}
```

```html
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="">one</a>
        <a href="">two</a>
    </div>
```